What does "to" mean in "The figure for Japan rose sharply to reach 2 million cars in 2010"?
I've seen this usage of "to" pretty often in data reports:


"Then, the figure for Japan rose sharply to reach 2 million cars in 2010."


I guess to here doesn't mean in order to. Perhaps to reach here means and reached. Am I right? If I am, maybe the following sentence is correct?


40 thousand British citizens relocated to Australia in 2004, with some subsequent fluctuations to peak at 51 thousand in 2006. (Or should it be peaking?)



You may want to consider "to reach" as a verb with "to" being a meaningless infinitival marker introducing the clause "to reach 2 million cars in 2010".

Interesting! So the second sentence must also be correct, isn't it?

Yes, both the to-infinitival and the participial clause are possible.

Instead of to peak, I might suggest that peaked.

Very useful advice, guys. Thanks a lot!

You could use "reaching" there instead of "to reach".  The non-finite forms are pretty much interchangeable there, though I think nowadays the participial form is more common in this sort of context, at least in American English.
